# Android inflates the wrong layout based on API version

Tags: android, android-layout

I have 2 layout files, one is the default layout and another for API 14 and above. Android seems to be inflating the default layout. I'm testing in on my phone which is on 5.1.0 API 22.

layout-v14\list_settings_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch1"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:text="Email Notifications"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_87"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/title"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_54"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <Switch
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>


</RelativeLayout>
```

layout\list_settings_header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="72dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/switch1"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:text="Email Notifications"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_87"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/title"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/title"
            android:layout_below="@+id/title"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:paddingStart="16dp"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black_54"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/checkbox"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="16dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The only difference between the two layout is the checkbox and switch. I'm seeing checkbox on my 5.1.0 phone.

I'm inflating the layout as a header of a listview:

```
 View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_settings, container, false);
        ListView listView = (ListView) view.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        View header = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_settings_header, listView, false);
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you decide which layout you want to inflate? I don't think it happens automatically.

Comment: added, im inflating is as a header of a listview

Comment: i just used switchcompat but it would be great if someone pinpoints the problem

Comment: @DanielJohnGomez Did you find a solution around this? I think I am having same problem, and it only happens to me when I upgraded SDK version from 21 to 22. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check the version manually in your code.

You can do it like this:

```
int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
if(currentapiVersion > 14){
    //inflate layout
} else {
    //inflate other layout
}
```

Comment: If the layout is in the layout-v14/ folder, Android should automatically use that instead of the default. There's no need to manually do that check.

Comment: Yeah it should automatically do that. But you can try if this works. If this doesn't work the problem is something else.

Answer (score 0):

**Your layout definition is totally correct**.
I really think that you are hunting a problem that doesn't exists: try to add an additional `View` (like a `TextView`) with a text like *"this is layout V-14"* in your *layout-v14/list_settings_header.xml* and check if it appears on your 5.1.0 device.

Comment: i did that too but it didn't show on my 5.1.0 device

Comment: @DanielJohnGomez The problem must be somewhere else. Are you using Android Studio? Do you tried to clean/rebuild etc?